# Error in scoreItems function in psych package: Columns not found

Tags: r, psych

A student of mine asked me the following question:

I was working through [this exercise](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/score-tests-with-r-exercise). Whenever I try this function from the psych package:

```
scoreItems(meta.bfi[,v$big5], ccases[,meta.bfi$name])
```

It comes up with this error:

```
Error: Columns `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `1`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `13`, 
       `14`, `15`, `11`, `12`, `16`, `17`, `18`, `19`, 
        `20`, `21`, `23`, `24`, `22`, `25` not found
```

What is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `scoreItems` is incompatible with tibbles (at least as of version 1.8.4).

If you convert the key to a pure data.frame, this should fix the problem:

```
meta.bfi <- as.data.frame(meta.bfi)
```

That said, scoreItems does expect row names, so in the future, you may need to add row.names again if tibble completely removes row.names from it's functionality (currently, they are deprecated).

#### Further background

The exercise is based on ProjectTemplate, and in version 0.8.2, ProjectTemplate began defaulting to converting data.frames to tibbles (https://tibble.tidyverse.org/ ) . While tibbles are similar to data.frames, they are not identical. They do cause issues with some functions that expect a pure data.frame.

There is discussion about whether this conversion to tibbles will be optional in a future release of ProjectTemplate:
https://github.com/KentonWhite/ProjectTemplate/issues/271